# DataLoader with custom Dataset does not work

Tags: pytorch, dataset, pytorch-dataloader

I'm new and I have a problem with a project I'm developing with Pytorch (Autoencoders for anomaly detection).

I have a very large training set composed of over 400000 images, each of size (256,256,4), and in order to handle it in an efficient way I decided to implement a custom Dataset by extending the pytorch corresponding class. The images are contained in a folder called DATASET, which contains another folder called "train", which contains another folder called "clean" with all the images of the training set. Same for the test set, where there's a folder called "test", inside of which there are other folders with images corresponding to specific labels. The DataSet class apparently works, but when I create the corresponding Dataloader it doesn't work anymore.

This is the implementation of my Dataset:

```
class ImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, directory, transform=None):
        self.paths = list(paths.list_images(directory))
        self.transform = transform
        self.classes, self.class_to_idx = torchvision.datasets.folder.find_classes(directory)  
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.paths)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = Image.open(self.paths[index])
        if self.transform:
            img = self.transform(img)
            
        label = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(self.paths[index]))    
        class_idx = self.class_to_idx[label]
        return img, class_idx
    
    def get_classes(self):
        return self.classes
        
    def get_name(self, index):
        return self.paths[index]
```

where "directory" is the directory that contains the images.
"self.paths" is a list of paths to all the images inside the folder "directory".
"
As needed, I implemented the **len** method and also the **getitem**, where I open the img using Image.open and selecting the path corresponding to "index".
I also implemented other two methods that I need for another function.

This is how I get the train directory:

```
train_dir = Path('DATASET').joinpath('train')
```

If I try to create the Datasets for the training and the test, apparently it works:

```
dataset_to_split = ImageDataset(train_dir, transform=ToTensor())
test_dataset = ImageDataset(test_dir, transform=ToTensor())

print("Number of images in the whole train dataset: ", len(dataset_to_split))
print("Classes of the train dataset: ", dataset_to_split.classes, "\n")
print("Number of images in the test dataset: ", len(test_dataset))
print("Classes of the test dataset: ", test_dataset.classes)
```

I get the following output:

Number of images in the whole train dataset:  435404

Classes of the train dataset:  ['clean']

Number of images in the test dataset:  15055

Classes of the test dataset:  ['clean', 'dos11', 'dos53', 'scan11', 'scan44']

If then I try to print one element of the dataset like this:

```
print(dataset_to_split[0])
print("\n\n", test_dataset[15000])
```

I correctly get a tuple containing the tensor (so the image) and the label in both cases (for the labels I get 0 in the first case, 4 in the second, which is correct).
That's why I say that apparently it works.

But when I try to create the dataloader (for example considering the test_dataset, but with the other one the issue is exactly the same) it just does not print anything and the kernel enters in an infinite loop without doing anything:

```
batch_size = 10
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=os.cpu_count())
```

And then if I try to print the labels (or any other thing) in this way, it does not do anything:

```
for batch, label in test_dataloader:
    print(label)
```

Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: as you described, It seems the directory structure of the train and test are a little different. Such that the train directory has an extra `clean` level that test directory doesn't. can you make sure that is not making any problems?

Comment: Hi, I found out where the problem is, and apparently is related to the fact that num_workers > 0. This is a known problem for Jupyter Notebook on Windows, so by setting it to 0 everything works but it's extremely slow, which is bad because I have more than 400000 images only for the training set.